# Equivalent of numpy.add.at for scipy.sparse

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Is there anything like

```
sparse.add.at(a, indices, b),
```

or writing a Python `for` loop is the best we can do when we have duplicates in indices?

Comment: Duplicate indices in COO format inputs are summed when converted to CSR.  This question needs a [mcve].

Comment: More on the sparse handles duplicates, see this recent SO, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72040697/fastest-add-with-repeated-indices-np-add-at-sparse-csr-matrix